# Keeping the existing Ubuntu 16.04 data

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I want to keep my existing Ubuntu 16.04 with all the folders and files that I have now, after replacing my HDD.

My laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04 in a normal HDD, and is perfectly tailored to my needs (I would like to keep it this way), but I need to install Windows 10. Since I am doing this, I am planning to buy an SSD to upgrade my laptop.my plan to install Windows 10 first on the new SSD, and afterwards install Ubuntu 16.04.

Can I copy my actual Ubuntu system and after the fresh installation of the dual boot paste it over the new Ubuntu installation. (keeping my customized Ubuntu 16.04)?

I've been backing up my Ubuntu as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR). I wonder if I can use the same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I would not copy the actual program and system files. It is probably doable, but possibly quite a lot of trouble as well. Perhaps using something like [dd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning) if you want an exact clone. I would suggest that instead you just make a list of the extra software that you have installed and install that list once you have installed the fresh Ubuntu system.

You also need to copy the hidden '.' folders and .config folders under your home directory as all the user application specific configuration is stored here. You might want the /etc directory as well in case you have special config in Grub or ssh.

You might try to install a virtualbox installation to see if it works before committing to a full reconfiguration of your system.

Comment: thanks! but isn't it more work? because i still have to install both OS... and according to the backup procedure... should work. (i guess... since its the same machine). but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Settings change between releases so an old settings file might be more problematic. I myself have a text file with all kinds of "apt-get" commands in it that I run after installing. It removes software I dont need and adds all I do need; including setting up my /home/ dirs to a partition. 1 script. Takes about 5 minutes to make and it is re-useable.